# Filter API Object Array by Matching Object Properties

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, filter

I am trying to filter my current array conditionally based on if values from a dynamic array match my static array.

`nfts` is my dynamic array, this changes based on user. This array contains all the metadata, images, transaction information etc. Specifically I am targeting `nfts.meta.name`, which returns a string eg. `Moonwalker #2`

`isLinked` is the static array, there are pre determined strings that may or may not match nfts.meta.name properties of the first array.

I can get it to return a list of all the filtered `nfts.meta.name` properties, but I need the whole of the new filtered `nfts` array to be returned, not just the `meta.names`.

Does anyone know a way around this ? Here is my code for getting the filtered nft.meta.name's

```
const filter = () => {
        const nftsId = nfts.map(x=> x.meta.name) //"Moonwalker #2", "Moonwalker #3",
        const isLinked = songList.map(x => x.id)//"Moonwalker #2", "Moonwalker 42"
        const filteredData = nftsId.filter((val) => {
        if (hasNFTs)return isLinked.find((a) => {
            return val == a
            console.log(filteredData) //"Moonwalker #2" 
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Seems like you want `nfts` array elements when the `.meta.name` is present in `songList` array elements' `id` prop. May be try something like so: `const filteredData = nfts.filter(nObj => (songList.map(({id}) => id).includes(nObj.meta.name)));`. That should get you `nfts` filtered to have only those elements (elements with all props, and not just `meta.name`) where `meta.name` matches at least some `id` within `songList` array's elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for the comment, you were spot on, I needed to filter nfts array not nftsId array. My final code for this looks like this

```
const filter = () => {
        const isLinked = songList.map(x => x.id)
        const filteredData = nfts.filter((x) => {
        if (hasNFTs)return isLinked.find((a) => {
            return x.meta.name == a
            console.log(filteredData)
        })
    })
}
```

This gives me all the array properties, not just the nfts.meta.name properties!